# Is $ (x^3+1)^{30} $ the derivative of $(\int_0^{x} \ (t^3+1)^{10} \mathrm{d}t)^{3} $?

Tags: calculus

Is $ (x^3+1)^{30} $ the derivative of $(\int_0^{x} \ (t^3+1)^{10} \mathrm{d}t)^{3} $ 
I tried to enter this in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+%28integral+from+0+to+x+%28%28t%5E3%2B1%29%5E10%29%29%5E3):

But I have a solution here that says this is wrong. So this makes me confused. What's going on here?

[image]

UPDATE 1: After [fixing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B%20%28integral%20from%200%20to%20x%20of%20%28t%5E3%2B1%29%5E10%29%5E3%20%5D) the WolframAlpha query I got one form of the solution that looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to consider the chain rule.

Comment: @JMoravitz Could you be more precise and tell me where the chain rule is exactly missing?

Comment: In doing $\frac{d}{dx}[ (\int_0^x g(t)dt )^3]$ it becomes $3(\int_0^x g(t)dt)^2 \cdot \frac{d}{dx}[\int_0^x g(t)dt] = 3(\int_0^x g(t)dt)^2 \cdot g(x)$.  You instead went straight to the fundamental theorem of calculus and plugged in $x$ and then cubed after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see by the solution provided that, no, you do not have the correct derivative. You need to apply the chain rule: 
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Bigg(\bigg(\int_0^{x} \ (t^3+1)^{10}\mathrm{d}t\bigg)^{3}\Bigg) 
    &=
    3\bigg(\int_0^{x} \ (t^3+1)^{10} \mathrm{d}t\bigg)^{2}
    \;*\;\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_0^{x} \ (t^3+1)^{10} \mathrm{d}t \\
    &=
    3\bigg(\int_0^{x} \ (t^3+1)^{10} \mathrm{d}t\bigg)^{2}
    \;*\;(x^3+1)^{10} \\
    &=
    3\bigg(y^{\frac{1}{3}}\bigg)^{2}
    \;*\;(x^3+1)^{10} \\ 
    &=
    3y^{\frac{2}{3}}(x^3+1)^{10} \\  
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks, that is easier to understand for me than the solution. Do you also know how to fix the WolframAlpha query?

Comment: This seems to get what we need: `D[ (integral from 0 to x of (t^3+1)^10)^3 ]`. Your original had the cube inside the integral.

Comment: Thanks, That looks like a long solution (see also the alternative form, now also posted in the original question). WolframAlpha does not even show the step-by-step option for that one, do you have time to show that WolframAlpha's solution actually makes sense?

Comment: It looks like WolframAlpha just expanded $(x^3+1)^{10}$ and expanded $y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ by taking the integral and squaring it. Considering how long that expansion it, I would leave the solution as $3y^{\frac{2}{3}}(x^3+1)^{10}$.